# How to find intersection values on two non-linear graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HEBkm1KUdKWbMOsNR6v-hDoIT1RSKFeg/view?usp=sharing

```
   clear all;close all;clc
    syms x y 
    [solx,soly] = solve(y+cos(x) == 0, (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-4 == 0)
```

I am able to get [x1,y1] cordinates that is [0.41864,-0.91364]. But, I am not able to find the other root.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) for [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) state that:

> If solve cannot find a solution and `ReturnConditions` is false, the `solve` function internally calls the numeric solver `vpasolve` that tries to find a numeric solution. For polynomial equations and systems without symbolic parameters, the numeric solver returns all solutions. **For nonpolynomial equations and systems without symbolic parameters, the numeric solver returns only one solution** (if a solution exists).

Basically, when your equations are nonpolynomial, you will get only one solution. You can get the other solution(s) by calling `vpasolve` directly, and passing an interval to it.

```
>> [solx,soly] = solve(y+cos(x) == 0, (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-4 == 0)
   [0.41864281074457462101303466040894, -0.91364150731035083238926541575963]
   

>> [sol2x,sol2y] = vpasolve(y+cos(x) == 0, (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-4 == 0, [1,5])
   [2.9999749446149569424146377450705, 0.98998896047356166485626815000393]
```

[image]